# Proper way to pass datetime from pyspark to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I'm trying to convert a spark dataframe to pandas but it is erroring out on new versions of pandas and warns the user on old versions of pandas.

On python==3.9, pyspark==3.4.0, and pandas==1.5.3, the warning looks as follows:

```
/Users/[me]/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:251: FutureWarning: Passing unit-less datetime64 dtype to .astype is deprecated and will raise in a future version. Pass 'datetime64[ns]' instead
  series = series.astype(t, copy=False)
```

I don't have a copy of the exact error on pandas==2.0.0, but it is basically the same thing, it wants you to pass datetime64[ns].

Here is the [line in pyspark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c4f7f137ed2262a782414e217520b29bca77f960/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py#L251) that is throwing this error.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do that is causing this error:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType, TimestampType, FloatType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
  SparkSession
  .builder
  .getOrCreate()
)

testAggData = [
  {
    'postId': '1234567',
    'title': 'Test1',
    'createdTSUTC': datetime.strptime('2023-04-19 03:14:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
  },
  {
    'postId': '1234568',
    'title': 'Test2',
    'createdTSUTC': datetime.strptime('2023-04-20 03:14:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
  }
]
testSchema = StructType([
  StructField("postId",StringType(),False),
  StructField("title",StringType(),False),
  StructField("createdTSUTC", TimestampType(), False),
])
testAggDataDf = spark.createDataFrame(testAggData, testSchema).toPandas()
```

Comment: I think I'm getting closer to the problem. Not sure if this is fixed in newer versions of pyspark but [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c4f7f137ed2262a782414e217520b29bca77f960/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py#L250) looks different than what my error is showing. My error code is referencing pyspark withing my spark installation and not the 3.4 that I pip installed in my environment. So I'm guessing I need to upgrade my spark installation

Comment: So I've confirmed the pyspark i'm importing is definitely 3.0.1 and not 3.4.0 like I thought and I think this is because I have `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/` in my PYTHONPATH and that location has the pyspark 3.0.1 installation. So I need to figure out upgrade or override that.

Comment: I fixed my path variables, now referencing the spark/pyspark 3.4.0 that I thought I was using. Still getting the warning/error though. Don't like seeing it, maybe will look into the codebase later and see if I can fix it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, [pyspark 3.4.0 requires pandas 1.0.5](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html). So I think I upgraded pandas when I was installing something else and didn’t realize this requirement. Downgrading pandas fixes this.